# Issue with preinstalled opencv libs on Raspberry Pi

Tags: c++, opencv, linker, raspberry-pi3, symlink

I recently ordered a Raspberry Pi 3 for a computer vision application. I noticed that it already the OpenCV 2.4.9 libs preinstalled, but when I tried to make use of them for a C++ program, I had some linker issues. I eventually realized that the folder containing the OpenCV libs was MISSING the necessary symbolic links that point to the actual OpenCV libs. For example, one typically finds 3 files for the opencv_core library:

1. libopencv_core.2.4.9.so
2. libopencv_core.2.4.so -> libopencv_core.2.4.9.so
3. libopencv_core.so -> libopencv_core.2.4.so

The first file is the actual library and the second and third files are symbolic links to the first and second files, respectively. Therefore, including -lopencv_core in the Makefile lets the linker find libopencv_core.so which points to libopencv_core.2.4.so which points to libopencv_core.2.4.9.so.

But on the Raspberry Pi I just ordered, I discovered the libopencv_core.so file was missing and so I had to rename libopencv_core.2.4.so to libopencv_core.so so that the linker would be able to find the opencv_core library. I also had to do this for the symbolic links to every other OpenCV library as well. So my question is this: Did the Raspberry Pi Foundation simple make a mistake when preinstalling the OpenCV libs on the Pi? Or is there some aspect of library linking that I am just ignorant of?